# Vista Task Scheduler Service Can't Be Stopped

Tags: windows-vista, services

I just noticed that I can no longer start, stop, or restart the Task Scheduler service. When I open a Command window and attempt to stop the service in that fashion, I get an "permission denied" error, even when running as Administrator.

Is there a solution to this issue?  I am running Vista SP1.

[image]

Comment: Please note that Microsoft has done this to prevent yo from stopping that service as it is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not disable Task Scheduler in Vista or Windows 7. Unlike XP, Vista actually uses Task Scheduler to perform system tasks.

Comment: I had to down vote this because it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: And what happens when the service malfunctions, and you have other user-critical tasks to complete prior to a Window restart? Microsoft cannot protect users from themselves with everything they could do to adversely alter the operation of Windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can't stop the task scheduler.  From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd363654(WS.10).aspx) ...

> The Task Scheduler service cannot be
>   stopped or disabled by administrators
>   using the Services Microsoft
>   Management Console (MMC) snap-in user
>   interface, unless special permissions
>   are added to the administrator token.

There are some registry tweaks that claim to get it to stop, but your best bet is to use a tool.  [Security Explorer](http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/security-explorer/) has a trial version that should work for you.  If you want to prevent users from scheduling tasks, [there is a way](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305612).

The best registry entry I found was below.  But I don't have a Vista machine to test it on.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Schedule]
"Start"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: I already have that Registry flag set with that value. Maybe I've never been able to disable it and never noticed before.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Schedule]
"Start"=dword:00000002
```

That is almost correct.  Set it to 4 and reboot to disable.  Some things will not work right such as updates (sometimes).  Just re-enable when you go to run updates.

Comment: Please note that this is a crucial service and should most likely not be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way to a stop and then start, or restart, services that are launched under accounts like the SYSTEM account, causing even an Administrator-context cmd.exe process not to be able to manage them.

1. Download [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
2. Extract all files in `ProcessExplorer.zip`.
3. Right click on resulting `procexp.exe` and select [image]`Run as administrator`; Click <kbd>Continue</kbd> button on resulting dialog.

[image]

4. Find `svchost.exe` in Process list, that has child process' of `taskeng.exe`.
5. Right click on the `svchost.exe` identified in step 4. and select `Properties`.

[image]

6. Select a Service; For the Task Scheduler click on Service `Schedule` line.
7. Click the <kbd>**P**ermissions</kbd> button.
8. Add at least `Write`, if not `Full control` permissions to a group your user account belongs to, or just your user account, and click <kbd>**O**K</kbd> button.
9. With the permission-changed service line still highlighted in the list, happily Restart or Stop (and the Start again, noting the consequences of not doing so in other answers to this question) your permission-changed service.

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior I'm seeing too.

There is a check box under the 'Services' tab of msconfig for 'Task Scheduler' though.  Maybe that would be worth exploring?

Comment: if you uncheck this box - it just immediately rechecks itself